# Java: Lucene Document Serialize

Tags: lucene, java

Доброго времени суток.
Возникла необходимость сериализации объекта org.apache.lucene.document.Document

К сожалению, пока что особо не представляю как это можно сделать. Пытался копать интернет - не получилось. Ранее был имплементирован интерфейс Serializeble, но его убрали почему-то :-( Подскажите, пожалуйста, где и что я не так делаю.

Comment: http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/api/all/org/apache/lucene/document/Document.html написано что сериализуемый, если по факту нет, то может им багрепорт написать?

Comment: @Rustam с версии 4.0 они отказализь от сериализации. Баг-репорт не поможет.

Answer (score 1):

Рассмотрите возможность реализации собственной сериализации. В конце концов Document - это всего лишь набор полей и их значений.